# Null ref exception UseWhen UseHttpsRedirection?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I can't get it. I'm trying to use UseHttpsRedirection conditionaly but keep getting null ref exception on builder.UseHttpsRedirection() line. What am I missing??

I use core 6.0.4

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var wab = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    var wa = wab.Build();
        wa.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/exercises"),
            builder =>
            {
                builder.UseHsts();
                builder.UseHttpsRedirection();
            });
    
    wa.Run();
}
```

Comment: provide some info about he exception like which line and stacktrace

Comment: Seems to be a bug in 6.0.4, try upgrading the version, thanks

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42959 upgrade your .net to the latest (6.0.12) and everything should work well.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments this is a bug in `UseHttpsRedirection` itself, not related to your code specifically. Upgrading the .NET version to the latest 6.0 release (really anything after 6.0.9) should work.

If that is or some reason not possible, in the github issue that Taras Kovalenko linked there is also the following suggestion for a workaround:

```
((IApplicationBuilder)app).Properties["server.Features"] = ((IApplicationBuilder)app).ServerFeatures;
```

See: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42959#issuecomment-1198070646